# What happened to Wesley's nanites?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-eu, nanotechnology

In ST:TNG episode "[Evolution](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Evolution_%28episode%29)", we see that Wesley's nanites are dropped off on Kavis Alpha IV. Do we ever hear of these particular species of nanites ever again (perhaps in sources other than the TV series)?

[Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Nanite) doesn't give us much on this, basically what's below:

> In 2366, nanites threatened the USS Enterprise-D with destruction of its main computer core during an experiment in the Kavis Alpha sector. After conflict with the crew of the Enterprise, and particularly the experiment's lead scientist Paul Stubbs, the nanites were relocated to Kavis Alpha IV, which Stubbs' influence had helped designate their new homeworld. The nanites left the Enterprise and began creating their own civilization on the planet. (TNG: "Evolution")

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Within the TV and Film Series, there's no further mention of Wesley's Nanites. The last we see of them, they've been abandoned on Kavis Alpha IV.

In the wider trek canon (books, etc), we meet them again briefly in [Immortal Coil](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Immortal_Coil) where they're referenced as being part of a wider pan-civilisational grouping of robot and machine intelligences living in and around the Planet Odin.

> Data felt pressure against his back. They were being borne upward by
>   another swelling of the silver clouds, pushed back up toward the
>   Enterprise. He looked at Rhea, who appeared calm, even relaxed, and
>   then felt her tapping against his forearm. She spelled out a word in
>   Morse code, but it wasn't necessary. Data understood now. It must have
>   been another one of Vaslovik's liberation projects, just like the
>   exocomps: Wesley Crusher's nanites, the microscopic robots that had
>   inexplicably developed into a sentient colonial artificial
>   intelligence. Shepherded here to Odin by Vaslovik, they thrived,
>   reproducing and evolving freely in the gas giant's immense
>   hydrogen-rich atmosphere.

Comment: I believe they were mentioned or at least alluded to in one of the Borg episodes as a potential weapon against the Borg. I want to say it was in Best of Both Worlds. It was a passing mention that nanites/nanotech could be used against the Borg, I believe made by Dr. Crusher. I don't remember if they specifically called out Wesley's nanites, however. I think it was the kind of reference that wouldn't leave new viewers wondering what they missed.

Comment: No, it's clear that they meant normal nanites, not Wesley's Nanites

Comment: crap - just realized - Wesely creating living beings makes him a god. Not to mention the traveler abilities. Stupid universe....

Comment: @NKCampbell - He didn't make the nanites, he just modified existing ones.

Comment: @Valorum He breathed life into them, in his sleep. Sounds pretty godly to me. Kneel before Wesley!

Comment: @Politank-Z - Try telling God to [shut up](https://youtu.be/OAqsU-BY58w?t=17s), Picard.

Comment: Actually, Wesley didn't even modify them, the premise was that they evolved. From TNG S3E1 'Evolution', Wesley: "I allowed two of the nanites to interact for a school project. I wanted to increase their capabilities... and they escaped." Wesley wasn't a god, he more closely resembles a scientific voyeur.